# How to link using GCC without -l nor hardcoding path for a library that does not follow the libNAME.so naming convention?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a shared library that I wish to link an executable against using GCC. The shared library has a nonstandard name not of the form libNAME.so, so I can not use the usual -l option. (It happens to also be a Python extension, and so has no 'lib' prefix.)

I am able to pass the path to the library file directly to the link command line, but this causes the library path to be hardcoded into the executable.

For example:

```
g++ -o build/bin/myapp build/bin/_mylib.so
```

Is there a way to link to this library without causing the path to be hardcoded into the executable?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The -l option of g++ has a ":" prefix that allows you to use libraries with unconventional file names.
The command

```
g++ -o build/bin/myapp -l:_mylib.so other_source_files
```

should search your path for the shared library with the file name _mylib.so.

Comment: I am finding that this results in `build/bin/_mylib.so` embedded in the library that was linked using `-l:` -  instead of embedding just `_mylib.so` as it normally does for standard sonames. As a result, when you try loading `_mylib.so`, it would be looking for that full path (`ldd` would show it) and won't find `_mylib.so` by itself.

Comment: this information is found in `man ld`: "On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for files other than libnamespec.a.  Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld will  search a directory for a library called libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.  (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.)  Note that this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a file called filename."

Comment: Like @EvgeniiPuchkaryov I'm using `-L/path/to/lib` & `-l:mylib.so` and still getting the full path hard coded to elf header. any ideas on how to solve this??

Comment: I ended up building a library with standard name, like `libmylib.so` and then renaming it to `_mylib.so` before placing it to the final destination

Comment: Thanks. And if I use CMAKE instead of explicit calls of `g++`, does CMAKE support `-l:` somehow?

Answer (score 3):

If you can copy the shared library to the working directory when g++ is invoked then this should work:

```
g++ -o build/bin/myapp _mylib.so other_source_files
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Unix or Linux I think you can create a symbolic link to the library in the directory you want the library.

For example:
`ln -s build/bin/_mylib.so build/bin/lib_mylib.so`

You could then use `-l_mylib`


[`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)