# Using SQLite3 in a C program - Simple setup issue

Tags: c, gcc, sqlite, mingw

I am new to programming and have just started to learn C. I would like to use SQLite3 in a c program but am having a hard time setting up the library. I am using old fashion command line interface to compile and run my programs. I am using gcc. I also tried using CodeBlocks and have spent alot of time researching on how to get this to work but no success!
I found a [C and SQLite3 tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) but it doesn't explain this simple concept of setting up the SQLite library with the GCC compliler. I also found another tutorial but it too doesn't explain how to set up the libary with the GCC compiler.

So far I have a simple program called "testsql.c" and this is all I would like to get working:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion()); 

return 0;
}
```

I am using the following gcc command to compile the program:

```
 C:\Users\qwa\Desktop\testsql>gcc testsql.c -o testsql -lsqlite3
```

The output is always this error:

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now I have been on [SQLite's download webpage](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and have downloaded the following files and have tried placing them under the MinGW\bin and MinGW\include:

```
 The Amalgamation zip file:
 shell.c
 sqlite3.c
 sqlite3.h
 sqlite3ext.h
```

I also downloaded the dll zip file hoping I could figure out how to link it with CodeBlocks but was unsuccessful. That zip file came with these files:

```
 sqlite3.def
 sqlite3.dll
```

I think my problem is that I just don't know how to make a connection between the SQLite3 libraries and the gcc compiler. I feel like this is such a noob question but I have been struggling :(

Any help would be extremely appreciated!!! To summarize, I just want a SQLite database connection setup with a simple C program.

**EDIT:** based on the first comment, I just used the following command:

```
  gcc testsql.c -o testsql -LC:\sqlite3\sqlite3.dll
```

and the result I got was:

```
 C:\Users\qwa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMjAu3h.o:testsql.c:(.text+0xf):undefined reference to `sqlite3_libversion'
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any ideas?

Comment: You could try specifying `-L/location/of/library` and/or `-l:sqlite3.dll` like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/281253/5781248 or `dlltool -U -d sqlite3.def -l libsqlite3.dll.a`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of using SQLite is to compile it directly into your application:

```
gcc testsql.c sqlite3.c -o testsql
```

Comment: omg thank you so much!!!!! wow all I had to do was to add "sqlite3.c" when compiling