# bazel: link to library that lacks 'lib' prefix

Tags: bazel

I have an external library `ace.so`.

```
cc_library(
    name='ace',
    hdrs=glob(['path/to/ace/**']),
    srcs=['path/to/ace.so'],
)
```

How do I go about linking to that library with bazel? I know [a colon can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207069/how-to-link-using-gcc-without-l-nor-hardcoding-path-for-a-library-that-does-not) when invoking gcc/g++ directly, but I'm not sure how to get the same behavior from bazel.

- I tried adding `-l:ace.so` (also `-Wl,-l:ace.so`) to `copts` but it seems bazel doesn't pass that to gcc *or* add it to the `@` file used for linker args.
- I tried `nocopts='-lace.so'` in combination with `linkopts=['-l:ace.so']`. No luck.
- I also tried `cc_import` instead of `cc_library`, but that didn't work either.

I've read the [Importing precompiled C++ libraries](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hK2mWl3TYNL9oJYX_S020TKkXZvBw1aBoYERvTHVyfg/edit?ts=597b4f3d#) doc, but I didn't see anything about using libs with an arbitrary prefix - or with no prefix.

As a temporary fix, I've added a symlink `libace.so` pointing to `ace.so` and changed the `srcs` line to match. While this works, I'd much rather convince bazel to use the lib as is.

Comment: I've tried, but did not get through. Could you, please, correct your post. You are referring to `:` as semicolon in the first paragraph bellow code block, but it is a colon.

Comment: @OndrejK. Fixed. I realized I'd made a mistake after posting, but didn't see it as serious enough to bother fixing - it's quite obvious from the linked page, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around how information about libraries is being collected and passed around, I am afraid this (assumption that "plain" dynamic libraries are prefixed with `lib` and `libfoo.so` can be given as `-lfoo` is fairly hard coded at the moment. The same would not be true of it was considered a "versioned" (matches a pattern `"^.+\\.so(\\.\\d+)+$"`) dynamic library, which would be passed as `-l:foo.so.1`. But unfortunately that does not really help you, because you'd still need to employ a similar workaround and create a fiction of versioning to boot. That said, as long as your solib filenames are given, the symlink sounds like a reasonably sane workaround.