# Swift package dependency with unsafe build flags: target integrity error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dlib, swiftpm

#### TL;DR

I am getting the following error for a local Swift package dependency when attempting to use it within an iOS project in Xcode:

`The package product 'DlibWrapper' cannot be used as a dependency of this target because it uses unsafe build flags.`

(I am using unsafe flags to specify static library location)

I also tried to import the package as a remote branch-based dependency but it fails anyway.

According to [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0238-package-manager-target-specific-build-settings/18341/10) on Swift forums the issue was addressed a while ago and a corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2254) was already merged.

The problem appears both with Swift 5.2.4 (Xcode 11.6) and 5.3 (Xcode 12 beta 3).

Any clues what could be the issue?

---

#### Details

I am trying to build a Swift package that wraps [dlib](http://dlib.net/) library and use it within an iOS app. Because of the platform I can't use the `.systemLibrary` target to link the `dlib`. So I precompiled it in a static lib and packaged together with the wrapper code like so:

```
DlibWrapper/
  Libraries/
    dlib/
      include/
          ...
      lib/
        arm64/
          libdlib.a

  Sources/
    CWrapper/
      include/
        module.modulemap
        cwrapper.h
      cwrapper.cpp

    SwiftWrapper/
      SwiftWrapper.swift

  Package.swift
```

Simplified contents of the `DlibWrapper/Package.swift`:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "DlibWrapper",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "DlibWrapper",
            targets: ["CWrapper", "SwiftWrapper"])
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SwiftWrapper",
            dependencies: ["CWrapper"]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "CWrapper",

            cxxSettings: [.headerSearchPath("../../Libraries/dlib/include")],

            linkerSettings: [
                .linkedLibrary("dlib"),
                .linkedFramework("Accelerate", .when(platforms: [.iOS])),

                // The error is caused by this line
                .unsafeFlags(["-LLibraries/dlib/lib/arm64"], .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx1z
)
```

I tried to use the `link` property inside the `module.modulemap` but compiler seems to ignore it. Also, giving an absolute path to the library in `.linkedLibrary()` in target manifest doesn't help, the linker complains it can't find the library.

Any ideas for workarounds? (As a last resort I would probably package everything in a framework)

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I just ran into this, too. My solution is to stop trying to build Swift Packages of third-party libraries. I'm going to try to build Xcode projects for them instead.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Turns out the method below doesn't actually work. Swift completely ignores `.linkedLibrary` when the package is compiled as a static library (check with `swift build --verbose`). The setting is only used with dynamic libraries. Nevertheless, the `:` syntax does nothing in the latter case — the library cannot be found anyway.

(The answer below is kept for historical reasons, maybe it helps someone to find a solution)

---

#### Old answer

The workaround is to use the clang/gcc colon syntax in linker options, i.e. `-l:` (minus-el-colon). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281253/13647455) for more details.

Here is the relevant snippet from the package manifest:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "DlibWrapper",
    //...
    targets: [
        //...
        .target(
            name: "CWrapper",

            cxxSettings: [.headerSearchPath("../../Libraries/dlib/include")],

            linkerSettings: [
                // Note the `:` in front of the relative path
                .linkedLibrary(":Libraries/dlib/lib/arm64/libdlib.a", .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
                //...
            ]
        ),
    ],
    //...
)
```

#### Explanation

The `.linkedLibrary` linker setting essential provides the `-l` flag to the linker. So, whatever you put there as a parameter will be translated into something like this

```
swift build -Xlinker -l<your-linkedLibrary-string>
```

The `:` syntax allows one to specify a library with a non-canonical name, i.e. the actual file name. Finally, because the linker's work directory is set to package root we can supply it with the relative path to the library.

I still consider this as a workaround because the right way would be to have something like `librarySearchPath`, i.e. `-L` linker option, analogous to `headerSearchPath` in `cxxSettings`.

Comment: Xcode 13 allows you to use modules with unsafe flags when they are referenced by branch name.

Comment: I had similar issue yesterday: https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel/issues/133